# c++ read binary data from istream

Tags: c++, binary-data, istream

I have an istream and I have to read it into a buffer. I could not find a way to figure out the read_len once eof is encountered? I cannot use get because my file does not have delimeters.

It seems that the only option is to read it character by character, is it really the only option?

```
char buffer[128];
while(is.good()) {
     is.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
     size_t read_len = sizeof(buffer);
     if (is.eof()) {
         read_len = xxxx;
     }
     process(buffer, read_len);
}
```

Comment: [readsome](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check [`istream::gcount()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) which "*Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input operation*".

Example:

```
    while(is) {
         is.read(buffer, sizeof buffer);
         auto read_len = is.gcount();  // <- 
         if(read_len > 0)
             process(buffer, read_len);
         else
             break;
    }
```

You could also use [`istream::readsome()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome) - but note:
"*The behavior of this function is highly implementation-specific.*" which may or may not be an issue.